# Is $\ -\frac{4}{3}ac - a^5d^3\ $ a polynomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials

It looks to me that it is, but I am not sure. Could it be not a polynomial function because each monomial has more than one variable?

($a^5$ means a raised to the power of $5$)

(Sorry, my math is really bad and is not my field)

Comment: You can call this one as a multivariable or multivariate function as there are two variables, $a$ and $d$. With respect to a single variable, say $d$, then yes, it is a polynomial.

Comment: The coefficients need not be integers, so yes, this is a polynomial (in three variables) and can be interpreted as polynomial function $f(a,c,d)$

Comment: $f(a,c,d)=\ -\frac{4}{3}ac - a^5d^3\in \Bbb Q[a,b,d]$ is a polynomial. Here $\Bbb Q[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$ denotes the ring of polynomials in the variables $x_i$ with rational coefficients.

Comment: @Peter - Thank you!

Comment: @soupless - Thank you!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is $\mathbb Q[a,b,d]$ a typo ?

Comment: @Peter I fear, yes. It should be a $c$. Strange that there is no variable $b$ though. I suspect that the line before was about $\Bbb Q[a,b,c,d]$ in four variables. But the OP has given no link.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - This was on my son's math paper, so there is no link. I copied it exactly the way it was.

Comment: So what class exactly is your son attending? Is it commutative algebra or financial mathematics? Can you describe some more context?

Comment: @DietrichBurde - This is the first grade of senior high school. Just general algebra, so, using the terms in your questions, it must be commutative algebra (though I am not really sure I know what this term means). Definitely not financial mathematics.